# cost explorer removing tax nodejs

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cost-explorer

When I check for last day of the month I have seen the cost in cost explorer higher than usual, I believe this is a tax.

Therefore I want to remove the tax on last day.

I tried this, but it doesn't work

```
var params = {
            Granularity: 'DAILY',
            Metrics: [
                'NET_UNBLENDED_COST'
            ],
            Filter: {
                Not: {      
                    Dimensions: {
                      Key: "SERVICE",
                      Values: [ "TAX"]
                    }
                }
            },
            TimePeriod: { 
                End: lastDay,
                Start: firstDay 
            }
        };

var costexplorer = new AWS.CostExplorer({ region: 'us-east-1' });

costexplorer.getCostAndUsage(params, function (err: any, data: any) {
      if (err) {
           console.log(err, err.stack);
           reject();
      } else {
           let result: any = data['ResultsByTime']
           resolve(result); 
            }
        });
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I've also ran the exact same thing.
The `Values` are case sensitive so you need to write `TAX` as `Tax`.
There also an option to make it case insensitive.